# Install ROS lunar on fedora

Tags: ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying install ROS on Fedora

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro lunar -y
```

but i got this error

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
gazebo_dev: No definition of [libgazebo7-dev] for OS version [26]
```

I try this command

```
[ahmedadel@192 ros_catkin_ws]$ rosdep install -ay --os=fedora:26
```

and got this result

```
#All required rosdeps installed successfully
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271423/install-ros-lunar-on-fedora/) by [ahmedadelhekal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31934/ahmedadelhekal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
sudo dnf install --skip-broken python-empy console-bridge console-bridge-devel poco-devel boost boost-devel eigen3-devel pyqt4 qt-devel gcc gcc-c++ python-devel sip sip-devel tinyxml tinyxml-devel qt-devel qt5-devel python-qt5-devel sip sip-devel python3-sip python3-sip-devel qconf curl curl-devel gtest gtest-devel lz4-devel urdfdom-devel assimp-devel qhull-devel qhull uuid uuid-devel uuid-c++ uuid-c++-devel libuuid libuuid-devel gazebo gazebo-devel collada-dom collada-dom-devel yaml-cpp yaml-cpp-devel python2-defusedxml python-netifaces pyparsing pydot python-pyqtgraph python2-matplotlib
```

This tends to install everything needed to build ROS on Fedora

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2018-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-20**:
It would be really great if you could [contribute some rules](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html) to the database so we can use `rosdep` to manage dependencies on Fedora again.